# Apache POI 3.14 Writing SXSSF to ServletResponse OutputStream is corrupting workbook JSF

Tags: java, excel, jsf, apache-poi

In my webapp, I'm building SXSSFWorkbook objects to generate reports with roughly 30-60k records each. I kick off a process through a request to first fetch and build each SXSSFWorkbook.  I'm able to generate the report and open a FileOutputStream to export my object to my desktop(locally of course). However, I want to let user choose which report to download through a request(JSF)to the server. When I feed the OutputStream from the servlet response, I can download the .xlsx file but it tells me it's been corrupted. I've done some research, tried some different workarounds all with no results. Posted is my code. I'm kind of at a loss for what's going on here.

p.s. I was previously generating HSSFWorkbook objects and downloading them but they were starting to causing heap space issues. Hence, the switch to SXSSFWorkbook.

My command button

```
                <h:commandButton value="Download Report" styleClass="secondary-button"
                    action="#{backingBean.getLatestReport}"
                    id="thirdReportButton">
                </h:commandButton>
```

My action

```
public void getLatestReport() throws Exception {
    FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String templateName = "Report.xlsx";
    HttpServletResponse response = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    //workbookForLatestReport is a SXSSFWorkbook object
    try {
        if (workbookForLatestReport != null) {
            response = (HttpServletResponse) faces.getExternalContext()
                    .getResponse();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + templateName + "\"");

            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            workbookForLatestReport.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            workbookForLatestReport.dispose();
        }

        faces.renderResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I've done some research, tried some different workarounds all with no results. "_ What research? What workarounds? Can you post them? And did you actually check the content of the response? To see why it is corrupted? I'm sure you'll find the cause then and maybe even the solution. And tried with a plain text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to a solution with the aid of omifaces and changing some code around.

After I create my workbook, I use a ByteArrayStream to set a byte[] attribute on my model bean that can be referenced when the download listener from the jsf is clicked.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
byte[] workbookForLatestBytes;
XSSFXWorkbook workbookForLatestReport;
.
.
.

workbookForLatestReport = <generate the report here>
if(workbookForLatestReport != null){
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbookForLatestReport.write(bos);
    workbookForLatestBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    workbookForPreviousReport.dispose();
}
```

Here is the action being fired from my JSF code.

```
<h:commandButton value="Download Report"
                            styleClass="secondary-button"
                            action="#{productRuleAuditCompareBackingBean.getSecondReport}"
                            id="thirdReportButton"
                            rendered="#{not empty productRuleAuditCompareModelBean.workbookForLatestBytes}">
                        </h:commandButton>
```

My backing bean action is as follows. I reset the HTTP Response before writing the byte array to the response output stream.

```
public void getSecondReport() {
        FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            faces.getExternalContext().responseReset();
            this.prAuditCompareModelBean.getLatestReport();
            faces.responseComplete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            PODBException.wrap(e, PODBExceptionInformation.create(
                    PODBExceptionType.ERROR,
                    ProductRuleAuditCompareBackingBean.class.getName(),
                    "getting first report",
                    "Error while getting second report for download", "1"));
        } 

    }
```

Here I'm using Omniface Faces#sendFile method to write the workbook to the response outputstream.

```
public void getLatestReport() throws Exception {


    try {
        if (getWorkbookForLatestBytes() != null) {

            Faces.sendFile(getWorkbookForLatestBytes(), reportName, true);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I successfully accomplished similar task so I might be able to help you.

I've just ran your code (on Payara 4.1 using Chrome as browser) adding part that you omitted in your post

```
@ManagedBean(name = "backingBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean {
    //your command button should call getLatestReport and not getSecondReport() as in your original post
    public void getLatestReport() throws Exception {
        FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String templateName = "Report.xlsx";
        HttpServletResponse response = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        //workbookForLatestReport is a SXSSFWorkbook object

        //MY ADDITION START
        //I've created SXSSFWorkbook object since your post did't contain this part
        //100K rows, 100 columns
        SXSSFWorkbook workbookForLatestReport = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
        workbookForLatestReport.setCompressTempFiles(true);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = workbookForLatestReport.createSheet();
        for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < 100000; rowNumber++) {
            SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
            for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < 100; columnNumber++) {
                SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(columnNumber);
                cell.setCellValue("ROW " + rowNumber + " COLUMN " + columnNumber);
            }
        }
        //MY ADDITION END

        try {
            if (workbookForLatestReport != null) {
                response = (HttpServletResponse) faces.getExternalContext()
                        .getResponse();
                response.reset();
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=\"" + templateName + "\"");

                outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                workbookForLatestReport.write(outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
                workbookForLatestReport.dispose();
            }

            faces.renderResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It was working just fine and as expected.

I have 2 suggestions:

- your command button "calls" `action="#{backingBean.getSecondReport}"`
  but your managed bean action is named `public void getLatestReport`.
  Check out if it is typing error or not.
- compare your SXSSFWorkbook object creation code with my example. Are
  there any crucial differences?

Comment: If you post an answer with code that is sort of similiar, it is good practice to explicitly add in text what the differences are...

Comment: @Kukeltje, thanx for suggestion. I've improved my answer.

Comment: @DusanKovacevic I've updated my question with the appropriate action. I incorrectly copied the wrong button for the method I provided so that's not the concrete issue. I've gotten my code to run by changing the current response reset call to faces.getExternalContext().responseReset(); and setting the content type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet". The issue I'm facing now is that if I download the workbook twice, the second request fails saying the stream is closed. I've removed the dispose and the response.close method calls.